# Cannot resolve "array" in R.array.items (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know many questions like this one already exist, but I looked through them and couldn't find an answer.

For some reason the keyword "array" is underlined in red, and I am getting the error: Cannot resolve "array". I have built the project, checked my xml file, but I just cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
package com.example.listapp;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView myListView;
    String[] fruits;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
        fruits = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
    }
}
```

Also here is my strings.xml file (under res/values/strings.xml):

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">List App</string>

    <string-array name="items">
        <item>peach</item>
        <item>apple</item>
        <item>banana</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="prices">
        <item>$1.49</item>
        <item>$0.99</item>
        <item>$0.89</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="descriptions">
        <item>Fresh peaches from Georgia</item>
        <item>Fresh apples from Ohio</item>
        <item>Fresh bananas from California</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

The line with the error is:

> fruits = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);

[image]

Comment: It will be `R.string.items` instead of `R.array.items`

Comment: when I change it to fruits = res.getStringArray(R.string.items), then it is giving me an error: "Expected resource of type array"

Comment: please check my edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `res` to `getResources()`

Try like this:

```
final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
```

**`Clean`** and **`Re-Build`** your projct or **`Invalid Crashes/ Restart`**

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the error at the very top of my post

Comment: Bro replace `res` to `getResources()`. Please check my answer properly or just replace your line with my code.

Comment: It still the same, I don't know what to say. I am still getting red

Comment: Please `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` add this line above the `@Override` and try to `clean` & `Re-build` your project.

Comment: This is my own decision buddy. If your question is useful for other users then I will give you the upper vote otherwise I'm not giving you the upper vote. Either you give me or not. Thanks @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: It's OK. You may like my question and you may know its answer. @Ali

Answer (score 1):

```
 <array name="select_city">
        <item>Surat</item>
        <item>Ahmedabad</item>
        <item>Vadodara</item>
        <item>Anand</item>
        <item>Amreli</item>
        <item>Rajkot</item>
    </array>
```

then use like this

```
 String [] abc=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_city);
```

Comment: when I change it to fruits = res.getStringArray(R.string.items), then it is giving me an error: "Expected resource of type array"

Comment: use array instead of string-array in string.xml file

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
```

This will be work, If u still getting error, please 
**Build->Clean Project** or 
**File->Invalid Crashes/ Restart**

I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind this error is you have no `array.xml` file in values folder your are created `string-array` in `string.xml`

> Solution:

Create the `array.xml` file in values folder and copy & past all `string-array` to `array.xml`

[image]